# Getting an array created in one PHP page from another PHP page?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have created a function with a list of array in **functions.php**:

```
function country_specs(){

$country_specs = array(

array('cc1', 'Country1', 'M1'),

array('cc2', 'Country2, 'M2'),
        );
}
```

How can I call `$country_specs` array in another PHP page.
I tried the following :

```
country_specs();

  foreach ($country_specs as $key => $value) {
    echo $value[0];
  }
```

but ain't working.

Comment: you have to return the array inside the function and get it

Comment: Hint: google for `return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this code**

```
function country_specs(){

    $country_specs = array( array('cc1', 'Country1', 'M1'),array('cc2', 'Country2', 'M2'), ); 
    return $country_specs;
}
```

**call the function**

```
 $country_specs=country_specs();

    foreach ($country_specs as $key => $value) { echo $value[0]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including this into your 2nd php file:

```
include 'functions.php';
```

This should work.